# Angular 2 router resolve with Observable

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, rxjs5

After the release of Angular 2 RC.5 there was introduced router resolve. [Here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#resolve-guard) demonstrated example with Promise, how to do the same if I make a request to the server with Observable?

search.service.ts

```ts
searchFields(id: number) {
  return this.http.get(`http://url.to.api/${id}`).map(res => res.json());
}
```

search-resolve.service.ts

```ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, Resolve, ActivatedRouteSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import { SearchService } from '../shared';

@Injectable()
export class SearchResolveService implements Resolve<any> {

  constructor(
    private searchService: SearchService ,
    private router: Router
  ) {}

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<any> | Promise<any> | any {
    let id = +route.params['id'];
    return this.searchService.searchFields(id).subscribe(fields => {
      console.log('fields', fields);
      if (fields) {
        return fields;
      } else { // id not found
        this.router.navigate(['/']);
        return false;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

search.component.ts

```ts
ngOnInit() {
  this.route.data.forEach((data) => {
    console.log('data', data);
  });
}
```

Get `Object {fields: Subscriber}` instead of real data.

Comment: Please post the code that demonstrates what you tried.

Comment: I have updated question with code examples

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Don't call `subscribe()` in your service and instead let the route subscribe.

Change

```
return this.searchService.searchFields().subscribe(fields => {
```

to

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/first' // in imports

return this.searchService.searchFields().map(fields => {
  ...
}).first();
```

This way an `Observable` is returned instead of a `Subscription` (which is returned by `subscribe()`).

Currently the router waits for the observable to close. You can ensure it gets closed after the first value is emitted, by using the `first()` operator.

Comment: Thanks Günter. I was looking for a way to get it to return an observable. `.map` makes sense. However, now that I'm using `.map` in my resolver, the route never seems to resolve. I do get into my `.map` function in my resolver and I see my data there, but I never get into ngOnInit of my component. My resolver looks like this `return this.eventService.getEvents().map(events => events)` and my route looks like this `..., resolve: {events: EventListResolver}}`. See anything obvious that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @JimCooper Currently the router waits for the observable to close. You can ensure it gets closed after the first value is emitted by using the `take()` operator. I updated my questin.

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense. I suppose I could also fix it by making sure my `getEvents()` method terminates my observable sequence (i.e. triggering onComplete). Thanks!

Comment: I am getting error  TypeError: this.cs.getCrisis(...).map(...).first is not a function.

Comment: Ok, figured it out with import 'rxjs/add/operator/first';

Comment: Sorry, missed your previous comment. SO isn't very helpful in tracking what comments are read :-/ Glad to hear you figured it out.

Comment: I assume that `last` operator should work the same way, but in that case the route is not resolved, what is the difference?

Comment: I don't think `last` can work. You need `first` or `take(1)` because the observable isn`t closed. Until it's closed there is no last event.

Comment: Normally you would be making a `http` request in a route resolve service which won't require `first()` or `take(1)` because the `http` request completes after the first value in the sequence by definition. But thats not the case when using these other sources of data or when merging something like an `http` request with something like `router` observables (which don't complete).

Comment: In relation to this question, since this answer is using `map` instead of `subscribe` where `subscribe` has an error handler, how do we now check if it failed in the route resolver so we can reroute? I'd like OP's code `this.router.navigate(['/']);` as the content of the error handler. Is this possible?

Comment: You can just use `subsribe` instead of `map`, or sou can use `catch` to handle errors. What kind of error do you expect?

Comment: is it possible to get data updates in resolver? I mean after Observable.next()

Comment: Not sure what the question is about. If you pass an observable from the resolver to the component, you can subscribe to in in the component and het a series of values.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I receive an interface error when I try to use subscribe withh resolve: "Class incorrectly implements interface 'Resolve<boolean>'."

I see how I could use map and catch, but I've been using the new HttpClient module and the built in error handling there. 

How would you use subscribe instead of map here?

Comment: @A.Krueger I'd suggest to create a new question that includes your code. I can't tell from the error alone.

Comment: Using .first() is only useful if you are only ever going to have a single result. It is often the case e.g. with BehaviorSubject, that the first mapped value will be an empty object/undefined, and you need to wait for future results

Comment: Not sure what your point is. If you don't want the first event, then of course you shouldn't use `first()`. You can use for example `skip(1).first()`

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I'm just after figuring that I can use `.map.first()`, and add checks in my .map(), and only trigger `return result` when the correct result has been recieved. This works well, as it fires the complete(). I jumped the gun with with comment

Comment: You can also use `.filter(...).first()`

Comment: I was mistaken. If the map() gets called, then it triggers the complete(), regardless if I return a value or not. So the filter function will be needed. Thanks for the info

Comment: Right. `map()` is just used to convert a value to a different value. This is why I suggested `filter()`.