# Angular2 load data from backend before view loads

Tags: angular, ngoninit

I have written the service code like this to read from backend

```
getData(): any { 

    let headers = new Headers(
      {

      });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    return this.httpClient.get('https://link', options)
      .map((res: Response) => res.json())
      // .do(data => console.log('All data: ' + JSON.stringify(data)))
      .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));
```

and the code to load data

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.service.getData().subscribe(
      (res) => {this.Data = res},
      (error) => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
}
```

but here it's getting data after the view loads so it's giving error.

How to load the data before view loads??

Comment: Try the `async` pipe in your view.

Comment: i didn't get you?

Comment: if you are displaying something in your view... like `*ngFor="let d of Data"` add the async pipe like so `*ngFor="let d of Data | async"` IF that is your problem (error)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37611549/how-to-pass-parameters-rendered-from-backend-to-angular2-bootstrap-method/37611614#37611614

Comment: Warining: lots of docs to read! You may need [resolve guard](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#resolve-guard). If you do, and when you see no result, you may add `first` operator, like [so](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39066604/angular-2-router-resolve-with-observable).

Answer (score 1):

Best option is to use a Routeresolver. Resolvers are part of the route definition and intended to provide data before a route is activated.
So if the view is shown you can get the provided data in the ngOnInit.
You just have to  use your code to fetch data in the resolver

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Resolve, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { DataService } from './DataService';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class MyDataResolve implements Resolve<any> {

    constructor(private dataService: DataService) { }

    resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<any>|Promise<any>|any     {

        let id = +route.params['id'];
        return this.dataService.getRecords('MT_Entity', id);    
    }
}
```

**In the Component:**
     export class BesuchdetailComponent {

```
   ngOnInit(): void {
     // Initialize form values, Prepare for SELECTS, ...
     let rawdata: any;
     this.rawbobject = this.route.snapshot.data['myobject'];
   }
 }
```

**Add Routerdefinition:**

```
export const AppRoutes: Routes = [
{

    {
       path: 'objectdetail/:id',
       component: YourComponent,
       resolve: {
          myobject: BesuchResolve
       }
    },
  }
```

Comment: but it's used for route

Comment: somehow you have to navigate to a view. This would be the place to use a routeresolver

Answer (score -3):

Angular 2 is an OOP like Java and C++ using classes. I advice you to start using classes at your service file. The link below is a solution that you may be looking for. Hope this helps. Happy coding..

```
   Angular 2 , MEAN Stack : Receiving JSON instead of HTML
```

Comment: javascript doesn't work anything like java, It's just a disguise