# Resolve in Angular for multiple api calls

Tags: angular, observable, angular2-observables

I am trying to call 3 different APIs before a component loads using the Resolve.

This code below is written inside the resolve function and is returning an object with all response packaged.

**Now When The component loads, before I receive the response from server.. it returns null for each of the keys in the object returned.**

Please help how do I solve this kinda issue. How do I stop it from returning until the response is not received from the API.

```js
resolve() {
  this._apiFactory.getA().subscribe(response => {
     responseA = response;
  });
  this._apiFactory.getB().subscribe( response => {
     responseB = response;
  });
  this._apiFactory.getC().subscribe( response => {
     responseC = response;
  });

  return {
    'A': responseA ,
    'B': responseb ,
    'C': responseC 
  };
}
```

Comment: Possible Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43166214/merging-http-observables-using-forkjoin

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You were returning the before your subscriptions could get finished. Used [Fork Join](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html) to wait until all your `Get` requests are completed and then returning the result of the get requests in your required format..

**Update**

> Since Rxjs 6.5.0, forkJoin also accepts an object as an argument.

```
// dummy Observables
const obsArg = {
    A: of([1]).pipe(delay(1000)),
    B: of([1, 2, 3]).pipe(delay(2000)),
    C: of([1, 2, 3, 4]).pipe(delay(3000))
}

return forkJoin(obsArg)
```

---

I tried it in `Angular 6` and I was able to do it like:

```js
// dummy Observables
let a  = of([1]).pipe(delay(1000));
let b  = of([1, 2, 3]).pipe(delay(2000));
let c  = of([1, 2, 3, 4]).pipe(delay(3000));

 let join = forkJoin(a,b,c).pipe(map((allResponses) => {
   return {
     A: allResponses[0],
     B: allResponses[1],
     C: allResponses[2]
   };
 }));

 return join;
```

So, I manipulated the data in `forkJoin` and returned the `forkJoin` itself. see it here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xepafp?file=src%2Fapp%2FAPIResolver.ts

In angular2, something like this should work:

```js
resolve() {
    return Observable.forkJoin(
      this._apiFactory.getA(),
      this._apiFactory.getB(),
      this._apiFactory.getC()
    ).map((allResponses) => {
       return {
         A: allResponses[0],
         B: allResponses[1],
         C: allResponses[2]
       };
     })
}
```

Comment: Thanks Aashish, but it is still not helping. As you see it is a router resolve method which I am using for the first time. And I see that the router returns a nested observable rather then returning this object even before the forkJoin ends

Comment: @JEETADHIKARI: See the update, I took it from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39066604/angular-2-router-resolve-with-observable , I think first() should be fine here.

Comment: Hey Ashish. Thankyou so much. That solved the problem. :)

Answer (score 3):

As of RxJS 6.5+ the way to do it is:

```
return forkJoin({
  todos: timer(500).pipe(mapTo([{ title: 'forkJoin'}])),
  user: timer(500).pipe(mapTo({ id: 1 }))
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with `combineLatest` as well. See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-combinelatest-resolver?file=src/app/test-resolver.ts)

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Resolve, ActivatedRouteSnapshot } from "@angular/router";
import { of, combineLatest } from "rxjs";
import { delay } from "rxjs/operators";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class TestResolver implements Resolve<any> {
  constructor() {}

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) {
    let a = of([1]).pipe(delay(1000));
    let b = of([1, 2, 3]).pipe(delay(2000));
    let c = of([1, 2, 3, 4]).pipe(delay(3000));

    return combineLatest(a, b, c);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Don't use Subscribe instead you can return your observables as

```
let a= observable(1);
let b= observable(2);
let c= observable(3);
return forkJoin(a,b,c);
```

this will help you