# Router does not navigate to targeted component

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-ui-router, observable, angular-router-guards

I have a function that redirects a user to a page `Orders` if the user's state is `complete`, and to a `HOME` page if the user's state is not `complete`.

The `Orders` page has a `GuardService` that implements `canActivate`, and the `HOME` page does not have any guards.

I have some users with the `R_ORDERS` right and in a `complete` state who are not navigating at all. (ie they are neither routed to the `Orders` page nor the `HOME` page).

I can see that the HTTP requests retrieving the user's right is called but they are stuck in that page.

Is my issue related to this post ?
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39066604/angular-2-router-resolve-with-observable)

or to this article
[enter link description here](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-2-rxjs-common-pitfalls/)

Also, I have tried to add logs when the observable has completed but in that case, the log is never displayed in the console.

```js
return this.getList().subscribe((e) => {
        const right = new List(e).FirstOrDefault(
          (d) => d.code == securizedPath.keyCode
        )?.type;
        if (!right) return resolve("OFF");
        return resolve(right);
      },
        (error) => {
          console.log("Right store threw an error");
          console.log(error);
        },
        () => {
          console.log("Right list completed")
        }
);
```

thanks for your help

```js
async redirectTo() {
  this.loading = true;
  this.userState = await this.stateService.getToPromise(this.userId);


  if (this.userState.isComplete) {
     this.orderService.init();
     this.router.navigate([RouteNames.ORDERS]);
     this.loading = false;
     return;
  }

  this.router.navigate([RouteNames.HOME]);
  return;
  
}
```

The `RouteNames.ORDERS` has the following guard:

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root",
})
export class GuardService implements CanActivate {
  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private rightService: UserRightService
  ) {}
  canActivate(
    route: import("@angular/router").ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: import("@angular/router").RouterStateSnapshot
  ):
    | boolean
    | import("@angular/router").UrlTree
    | import("rxjs").Observable<boolean | import("@angular/router").UrlTree>
    | Promise<boolean | import("@angular/router").UrlTree> {
    return this.test(route);
  }
  async test(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) {
    const right = await this.rightService.isRouteAllowed(route.url[0].path);
    if (right == "OFF") {
      this.router.navigate([RouteNames.FEATURE_UNAUTHORIZED]);
      return false;
    } else if (right != "ON") {
      this.router.navigate([RouteNames.FEATURE_UNAUTHORIZED]);
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }


}
```

Code for the `UserRightService` is

```js
 isRouteAllowed(route: string): Promise<Right> {

    const securizedPath = new List(this.securizedPaths).FirstOrDefault(
      (e) => e.name == route
    );
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      return this.getList().subscribe((e) => {
        const right = new List(e).FirstOrDefault(
          (d) => d.code == securizedPath.keyCode
        )?.type;
        if (!right) return resolve("OFF");
        return resolve(right);
      });
    });
  }
```

`securizedPaths` is defined as below
`typescript[{ name: RouteNames.ORDERS, keyCode: "R_ORDERS" }, // other value ]`

and getList is

```js
 getList() {
    this.subjectList = new ReplaySubject<T[]>();
    this.load();
    return this.subjectList;
 }

protected load() {
      return this.getService()
        .getAll()
        .then((e) => {
          this.subjectList.next(e);
        })
        .catch((e) => {
          this.subjectList.next([]);
          this.subjectList = null;
        });
  }

// Code for this.getService().getAll()
  async getAll(id?: any, parameter?: any): Promise<Array<T>> {
    let urlParameters;
    ({ urlParameters, parameter } = this.createParameters(parameter, id));
    return this.http
      .get(this.url + (urlParameters ? "?" + urlParameters : ""))
      .toPromise<Array<T>>();
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am NOT* sure whether i understand your problem completely but based on reading i see something which i would like to propose you. I see some issue in GuardService

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: "root",
})

export class GuardService implements CanActivate {
    constructor(
        private router: Router,
        private rightService: UserRightService
    ) { }
    
    canActivate(
        route: import("@angular/router").ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
        state: import("@angular/router").RouterStateSnapshot
    ): Promise<boolean> {
        
        let resolver: (value: boolean | PromiseLike<boolean>) => void;

        const promise = new Promise<boolean>((resolve) => {
            resolver = resolve;
        });
        this.test(route, resolver);
        return resolver;
    }

    async test(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, resolver: (value: boolean | PromiseLike<boolean>)) {
        const right = await this.rightService.isRouteAllowed(route.url[0].path);
        if (right == "OFF") {
            this.router.navigate([RouteNames.FEATURE_UNAUTHORIZED]);
            return resolver(false);
        } else if (right != "ON") {
            this.router.navigate([RouteNames.FEATURE_UNAUTHORIZED]);
            return resolver(false);
        }
        return resolver(true);
    }
}
```

See code I have highlighted in bold.

I guess you must return a promise which will resolved in test method based on what value will be received in response.

My proposal is totally based some assumption which helped me to fix an issue in past where CanActivte method of the Gurad wanted to return a value asynchronously.

Comment: Incase there are compilation error you have to solve those your self, my edit is based on Notepad.

Comment: thanks. could you please tell me what's the difference between using subscribe and using promise ? I'm quite new to Front End dev. thanks.

Comment: I would suggest you to have a look at - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37364973/what-is-the-difference-between-promises-and-observables#:~:text=If%20the%20result%20of%20an,the%20result%20it%20provides%20anymore.