# Angular route - Resolver

Tags: angular-router

I am trying to accomplish the following challenge:
I have a route that I want to delay until another component gets fully rendered. I already have a resolver in that route and thinking to use it to delay route's component instantiation. How can I wait for an event from some component inside of route's resolver? I have found examples of subscribing to http events inside of a resolver:

[Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39066604/angular-2-router-resolve-with-observable)

, but I am not sure if that can be adapted to my needs. Please share any idea.

Thanks